# Python- How to configure and use Kinect

Tags: python, kinect

I have an Xbox 360 + Kinect. It's great fun to play on it, So, I was wondering if it was possible to use Python to use it and make my own games (and play on PC).
Currently,
I have
 1.Drivers from Microsoft and the hardware.(only)
 2.**No** experience with 3d programming.

**My Questions**
 1. Is there good and easy to use module for using Kinect on PC??
 2. And any books for the same??

I am using Windows 32 and 64 bit and Python 2.7.

Comment: Schoolboy, did you managed to build something since you last posted this? If so, can you share any links to show us what you had. I'm planning to experiment on my xbox 360 some day too.

Comment: @fedmich No, not really.. I only ended up writing some code to detect object(s) (Anything) closer than some distance to show "Move back" text. And after failing miserably, moved on in life... I was just looking around my files but I have switched machines and it seems the code is lost...

Answer (score 6):

There is a project called [Open Kinect](http://openkinect.org/wiki/Main_Page) which has many wrappers that you can make use of, including one for [Python](http://openkinect.org/wiki/Python_Wrapper).

To help you get started, there are a good few code demo's supplied with their source code, which can also be viewed online [here](https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect/tree/master/wrappers/python).

Once you've got to grips with making use of the information the Kinect is sending back to you, you can try the popular [pygame](http://www.pygame.org/wiki/about) to base a game around whatever it is you're trying to do.

Comment: What is Python-dev(mentioned [here](http://openkinect.org/wiki/Python_Wrapper#Dependencies))?? (I have NumPy,PyGame and CPython.)

Comment: I'm fairly sure this is a Linux only thing and is not required on Windows. Try without it and report back if you have any problems :). Judging by the demo's you may also need OpenCV and/or matplotlib.