# Static cast equivalent in python

Tags: python, casting, ros

My problem is the following:

I am using [ROS](http://ros.org/) and I am currently trying to read values from a PointCloud of a Kinect sensor.
The values are of type PointCloud2 and PointCloud2.data holds the data of the PointCloud and is of type uint8[].

In my project I am currently using python and I have successfully registered and retrieved the data. My issue is that when trying to retrieve them python parses the uint8[] array as strings.

The current part of the script where I have the problem is the follwowing:

```
def PointCloud(self, PointCloud2):
    self.lock.acquire()
        for x in PointCloud2.data:
            print x
    self.lock.release()
```

I know that in c++ I can do something like

```
 std::cout << static_cast< int >( u );
```

To get the value of the unsigned integer. Is there a static cast equivalent to python?

In my case print x outputs ASCII characters.
How could I retrieve the int value of that?

Cheers,

Panos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `struct.unpack` to get the integer value encoded by the binary data in `x`.

```
print struct.unpack("!I", x)
```

(I'm assuming `x` contains a 4-byte integer in network byte order; consult the documentation for the `struct` module if you need a format other than `!I`.)

---

Update: I missed that you have an array of unsigned bytes; in that case, use

```
struct.unpack("B", x)
```

Comment: Since he uses `unit8[]` he will need the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Python doesn't support casting in any form; it's evil.

One version to achieve what you want is convert the data to hex:

```
print ['%02x' % e for e in PointCloud2.data]
```

or you can use the [`struct` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) to convert binary data into Python structures. If you want to process the data, you should look at [Numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) which has an `array` type that you can [create from a lot of different source](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.creation.html).

For image processing, look at [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/). And for existing Python tools to work with Kinect, see [Python- How to configure and use Kinect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14458016/python-how-to-configure-and-use-kinect)