# Is there static_cast keyword or standard method in Python?

Tags: python, c++, static-cast

I got the following piece of code:

```
def DisplayListCurveKeys(pCurve, pProperty):
    lKeyCount = pCurve.KeyGetCount()

    for lCount in range(lKeyCount):
        lKeyValue = static_cast<int>(pCurve.KeyGetValue(lCount))
        lKeyTime  = pCurve.KeyGetTime(lCount)

        lOutputString = "            Key Time: "
        lOutputString += lKeyTime.GetTimeString(lTimeString)
        lOutputString += ".... Key Value: "
        lOutputString += lKeyValue
        lOutputString += " ("
        lOutputString += pProperty.GetEnumValue(lKeyValue)
        lOutputString += ")"

        print(lOutputString)
```

it uses `static_cast<int>` expression, which looks like from `C++`. Is it valid in Python?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30104945/static-cast-equivalent-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no `static_cast` in Python.

In the example you show, `pCurve.KeyGetValue(lCount)` (whose type is not apparent in the code) is being cast to an `int`. You could try replacing the `static_cast<int>` with just `int`. This will work if the original value is some kind of scalar number, or a string representing an integer.

For example `int('23') == 23` would evaluate to `True` in Python.

If you can provide some more information about the type of the expression `pCurve.KeyGetValue(lCount)` it might be possible to come up with a solution, if the `int(...)` approach does not work.

Comment: I think somebody was porting from C++ and forgot this part. Since I am new to Python, I was not sure Python disallows such construct.